# Can't warm boot with custom MOK

Tags: boot, encryption, 23.10

I can no longer **warm boot** after enrolling a self-signed **MOK**. However, there is no issue if I try to cold boot.

During warm boot, after I enter a decryption key for LUKS, I get a 'Set up successfully' message, and the system seems to be loading (the loading circle keeps spinning, and then disappears - as expected). Unfortunately, after a while, it gets stuck at the splash screen.

During cold boot, the steps are the same, but everything works just fine.

**Info**:

- ASUS TUF Gaming A15 laptop
- Ubuntu 23.10 (6.5.0-21-generic)
- SecureBoot is ON
- BIOS is password protected
- Drive is LUKS encrypted

Comment: did you have regard to [this Ubuntu blog post](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot)?

Comment: @graham, No, I didn't see that particular article. How will it help me if the certificate I created is successfully loaded upon each cold boot?